# Problem rendering a PDF file on mobile using ng2-pdf-viewer [Angular 12]

Tags: angular, pdf, mobile, sass, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

I'm using ng2-pdf-viewer to display a PDF file and it works perfectly on a desktop, but I'm having trouble displaying it on mobiles.

As soon as I test it on an Android device I'm met with a blank that only shows a blue button to download the file. Using the Toggle device toolbar shows a blank initially, if I change it back to desktop and then to a mobile device again it properly shows the PDF and the scrollbar, but of course this is not an option on mobile.

I tought maybe I had to use another library so I checked out ngx-extended-pdf-viewer, but I worry it's a much simpler matter and it all boils down to the .scss of the component.

[A screenshot of the pdf viewer on a phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjnn9.jpg)